# how to programatically check a date from a list of dates in a pivot table

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, pivot-table

I have encircled the checkbox list part in the image. I want to select a specific date from the list of dates in a pivot table. Can you please let me know how can i do it programatically. I am not able to move forward. unable to understand how to connect with the pivot table.I am new to .Net so please be lenient on my silly mistakes if any.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
String date;
...
try{
    PivotItem dateItem = pt.PivotFields("open date2").PivotItems.Item(date);
    if (dateItem == null) throw new Exception("Date not available");
}
catch{
    //handle error
}
```

Please try to search stackoverflow and the internet in general before asking questions. If you misunderstand a post that you have read, please include that in your question. If you need help with this issue, please comment, and I will help. If this post has sufficiently answered your question, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have searched on internet but not able to find an appropriate answer.I have searched through stack flow also.i am stuck for two days.

Comment: Can you try the post I linked? I believe that solves your issue

Comment: The link you have provided i am not able to get it and moreover they have used VBA, i need it in asp.net point of view. I just want to loop through OpenDate2 items and check one item.

Comment: I see now that you tagged asp.net. When using stackoverflow, please try to include as much information as possible in the body of your message, including what language you are using and code you have written. The image is a start, but it does not provide enough info on its own. Is there one specific date you need? Do you want to capture a date from user input? Do you want to loop through all values?

Comment: Depending on the user input date i want to check a date in the pivot table

Comment: If this does not help you, I will need to see your code to get to the bottom of this. If it does, please remember to upvote and mark correct.